# why the edit text is invisible when i restart the application?

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

I am trying to make a simple application where after pressing a button edit text will be added, I would like it to be saved after typing anything in the edit text. when restarting the application I would like to see edit text that contains something. I don't know why when I restart applications, the data from the edit text is saved but the edit text is invisibile again. this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String PREFERENCES_NAME = "myPreferences";
private static final String PLIK_GLOWNEJ_KWOTY = "text_plik_glownej_kwoty";
private static final String PLIK_E1 = "text_pliku_e1";


private EditText WpiszKwote;
private TextView WpisanaKwota;
private Button Przycisk;
private Button Zapisz;
private EditText e1;
private EditText e2;
int x = 0 ;

private SharedPreferences preferences;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //inicjalizacja pola

    WpiszKwote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.WpiszKwote);
    WpisanaKwota = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WpisanaKwota);
    Przycisk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Przycisk);
    Zapisz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Zapisz);
    e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(e1.getText().toString())) {
        e1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {
        e1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(e2.getText().toString())) {
        e2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    restoreData();

    //nasłuchiwanie pola edytowania textu

        WpiszKwote.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String wpisana = WpiszKwote.getText().toString();
                WpisanaKwota.setText(wpisana);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        // nasłuchiwanie przycisku


    Przycisk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            x++;
            Runnable run = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    x = 0;
                }
            };

            if (x == 1) {
                e1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (x == 2) {
                e2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });


        // nasłuchiwanie przycisku zapisywania


        Zapisz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveData();
                showToast("Dane zostały zapisane");

            }
        });


}
private void saveData() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = preferences.edit();
    String editTextData = WpiszKwote.getText().toString();
    String editTextData1 = e1.getText().toString();
    preferencesEditor.putString(PLIK_GLOWNEJ_KWOTY, editTextData);
    preferencesEditor.putString(PLIK_E1, editTextData1);
    preferencesEditor.commit();
}
private void restoreData() {
    String text_pliku_glownej_kwoty = preferences.getString(PLIK_GLOWNEJ_KWOTY, "");
    WpisanaKwota.setText(text_pliku_glownej_kwoty);
    String text_pola_e1 = preferences.getString(PLIK_E1, "");
    e1.setText(text_pola_e1);

}
private void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: It is gone because when the app starts your edittext is empty. Just execute restoreData method before your if clause so your edittext is not empty and pass your validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's because You first check if the `e1.text` is empty and then `restoreData()`. You first have to restore data and then check if it is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Change this

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(e1.getText().toString())) {
    e1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else {
    e1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(e2.getText().toString())) {
    e2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
restoreData();
```

to

```
restoreData();
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(e1.getText().toString())) {
    e1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else {
    e1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(e2.getText().toString())) {
    e2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Hope it Helps